# JSON from streamed data in Python

Tags: python, jython-2.5

I am simply trying to keep the following input and resulting JSON string in order.

Here is the input string and code:

```
import json

testlist=[]
# we create a list as a tuple so the dictionary order stays correct
testlist=[({"header":{"stream":2,"function":3,"reply":True},"body": [({"format": "A", "value":"This is some text"})]})]

print 'py data string: '

print testlist

data_string = json.dumps(testlist)

print 'json string: '

print data_string
```

Here is the output string:

```
json string: 
[{"body": [{"format": "A", "value": "This is some text"}], "header": {"stream": 2, "function": 3, "reply": true}}]
```

I am trying to keep the order of the output the same as the input.

Any help would be great.  I can't seem to figure this one point.

Comment: Not clear. Any code example?

Comment: Not really doing what I want but here is where I am:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Laurent wrote your question is not very clear, but I give it a try:

`OrderedDict.update` adds in the above case the entries of `databody` to the dictionary.
What you seem to want to do is something like `data['body'] = databody` where `databody` is this list 
`[{"format":"A","value":"This is a text\nthat I am sending\n to a file"},{"format":"U6","value":5},{"format":"Boolean","value":true}, "format":"F4", "value":8.10}]`
So build first this list end then add it to your dictionary plus what you wrote in your post is that the final variable to be parse into json is a list so do `data_string = json.dumps([data])`

Comment: Trying to get the datastring made or put together is the problem.  It is how to get it into the format that you have posted above so the JSON command creates the proper string.  That is what I am having trouble with.

Comment: Sorry, but you need to be a bit more concrete and please have first a look at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html to learn how to manipulate the basic data structures in python. There you learn how to construct dictionaries, lists, etc.